# Documentation for MIPS predefined macros

Tags: gcc, mips

When I compile a C code using GCC to MIPS, it contains code like:

```
daddiu  $28,$28,%lo(%neg(%gp_rel(f)))
```

And I have trouble understanding instructions starting with **%**.

I [found](https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/MacrosHelp.html) that they are called macros and predefined macros are dependent on the assembler but I couldn't find description of the macros (as %lo, %neg etc.) in the [documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.37/as/index.html) of **gas**.

So does there exist any **official** documentation that explains macros used by GCC when generating MIPS code?

EDIT: The snippet of the code comes from [this](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:21,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:21,positionLineNumber:9,selectionStartColumn:21,selectionStartLineNumber:9,startColumn:21,startLineNumber:9),source:%27//+Type+your+code+here,+or+load+an+example.%0Aint+g(int+x)%0A%7B%0A++++return+x+*+x%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+f(int+x)%0A%7B%0A++++return+g(x)+%2B+2%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:mips564,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27MIPS64+gcc+5.4+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) code.

Comment: FYI, just as a side note, best to view compiler generated code using -O3, since that takes out a lot of noise.  However, in the case of the sample you're using it will also inline method `g` which you don't want here, so, remove the definition of `g` from the compilation unit (source) and replace it with a mere declaration: `extern int g(int);` then use -O3.

Comment: @ErikEidt To get rid of directives and macros, compiling the code to an object file using `gcc -c code.c` and than dumping .text section using `objdump -S code.o` gives me a good result.

Comment: Do you know any way to do that on godbolt.org?

Comment: @ErikEidt You can try to check **Compile to binary** in _Output..._ menu. But I don't know if it does the same thing as I wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

- This is a very odd instruction to find in compiled C code, since this instruction is not just using `$28`/`$gp` as a source but also updating that register, which the compiler shouldn't be doing, I would think.  That register is the global data pointer, which is setup on program start, and used by all code accessing near global variables, so it shouldn't ever change once established.  (Share a godbolt.org example, if you would.)
- The functions you're referring to are for composing the address of labels that are located in global data.  Unlike x86, MIPS cannot load (or otherwise have) a 32-bit immediate in one instruction, and so it uses multiple instructions to do work with 32-bit immediates including address immediates.  A 32-bit immediate is subdivided into 2 parts — the top 16-bits are loaded using an `LUI` and the bottom 16-bits using an `ADDI` (or `LW`/`SW` instruction), forming a 2 instruction sequence.
- MARS does not support these built-in functions.  Instead, it uses the pseudo instruction, `la $reg, label`, which is expanded by the assembler into such a sequence.  MARS also allows `lw $reg, label` to directly access the value of a global variable, however, that also expands to multiple instruction sequence (sometimes 3 instructions of which only 2 are really necessary..).
- `%lo` computes the low 16-bits of a 32-bit address for the label of the argument to the "function".  `%hi` computes the upper 16-bits of same, and would be used with `LUI`.  Fundamentally, I would look at these "functions" as being a syntax for the assembly author to communicate to the assembler to share certain relocation information/requirements to the linker.  (In reverse, a disassembler may read relocation information and determine usage of `%lo` or `%hi`, and reflect that in the disassembly.)

I don't know `%neg()` or `%gp_rel()`, though could guess that `%neg` negates and `%gp_rel` produces the `$28`/`$gp` relative value of the label.

---

`%lo` and `%hi` are a bit odd in that the value of the high immediate sometimes is offset by +1 — this is done when the low 16-bits will appear negative.  `ADDI` and `LW`/`SW` will sign extend, which will add -1 to the upper 16-bits loaded via `LUI`, so `%hi` offsets its value by +1 to compensate when that happens.  This is part of the linker's operation since it knows the full 32-bit address of the label.

---

That generated code is super weird, and completely different from that generated by the same compiler, but 32-bit version.  I added the option `-msym32` and then the generated code looks like I would expect.

So, this has something to do with the large(?) memory model on MIPS 64, using a multiple instruction sequence to locate and invoke `g`, and swapping the `$28`/`$gp` register as part of the call.  Register `$25`/`$t9` is somehow also involved as the generated code sources it without defining it; later, prior to where we would expect the call it sets `$25`.

One thing I *particularly* don't understand, though, is where is the actual function invocation in that sequence!  I would have expected a `jalr` instruction, if it's using an indirect branch because it doesn't know where `g` is (except as data), but there's virtually nothing but loads and stores.

There are two additional oddities in the output: one is the blank line near where the actual invocation should be (maybe those are normal, but usually don't see those inside a function) and the other is a `nop` that is unnecessary but might have been intended for use in the delay slot following an invocation instruction.

Comment: Thank you for such a long answer, but I can't mark it as an answer, I am sorry, because my question is asking for the documentation. I can find documentations for MIPS64, for some of pseudo-instructions and for System V ABI, but macros used by gcc are black magic to me.